# How to know if selection-screen is filled or not?

Tags: abap, sap-selection-screens

I have selection screen with **SELECT-OPTION** let say the name is `selection_kunnr` and I want to know if user filled that selection area or not

Note: this `selection_kunnr` is not a mandatory field. How can I deal with it?

I have tried so far

```
if selection_kunnr is not initial.
  "do some action here
endif.
```

but I think it doesn't work at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: sorry..
I have the answer it should be selection_kunnr[] instead of selection_kunnr because of multiple selection

and the condition check shoul be in at-selection-screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELECT-OPTIONS create an internal table (same as the RANGE statement) for a field. (It creates 4 fields: SIGN, OPTION, LOW and HIGH). You can check whether the table has any contents by using:

```
IF SELECTION_KUNNR[] IS INITIAL.
```

The [] operator specifies the contents (rows) of an internal table.

I am not sure anymore, because I am not in front of an SAP system right now, but if only the initial FROM/TO fields are filled, I am not sure whether this creates an entry in the table.

HINT: In the ABAP editor, you can place the cursor on any statement, and press F1 to get help on that statement.

Answer (score 0):

Given that this creates an internal table you can also use the DESCRIBE statement. Which works just as well on ranges and internal tables in your program.

DESCRIBE TABLE  LINES w_count.